# Rspec tests running in wrong environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, solr, rspec, sunspot

I have an integraton test that is run using selenium. In my before each i build a few objects and index with solr.  I can see the activity in my subnsspot solr test log.  And then in my test I perform a search and get an error because my sunspot solr server isn't running.  That's because it's running with RAILS_ENV = test.

Here's my before each:

```
before :each do
 Sunspot.remove_all!(Residential)
 Sunspot.commit

  @prop1 = FactoryGirl.create(:residential, { subdivision: "Steiner Ranch", street_name: "propone" })
  @prop1.index!
  @prop2 = FactoryGirl.create(:residential, { subdivision: "Jester Estates", street_name: "proptwo" })
  @prop2.index!
  @prop3 = FactoryGirl.create(:residential, { subdivision: "Cypress Ranch", street_name: "propthree" })
  @prop3.index!
end
```

And here is my test:

```
it "single word", :js => true do
  visit '/'
  fill_in 'subdivision', :with => 'cypress'
  page.should_not have_content('propone')
  page.should_not have_content('proptwo')
  page.should have_content('propthree')
end
```

Any idea why the search is running in development environment and not test environment? I have  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test' as the first line in my spec_helper.

Comment: Turns out I was setting my environment inside my Spork config but wasn't running spork at the time.

Answer (score 8):

I had this same issue. It turns out the Rails app I had running actually specified ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'development' in a configuration file (an Apache config file since we are using passenger).

If this is the case for you, then you can replace

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
```

with

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
```

in your spec_helper.

I did that since

1. we don't have RSpec on our production machines and
2. we don't run tests in production.

Comment: That didn't work.  And if I log what the current environment is during both the before and the test, it says 'test' but it still looks for the 'development' sunspot server.